What do Jews call the deuterocannonical books?
In theory, the Christian “Old Testament” is the same as the Jewish Bible, or at least the same texts in a different order, but in fact there are a few different versions of the Old Testament. The Catholic and Orthodox churches both accept some books which Jews (and also Protestants) don’t.
The branches of Christianity which accept those books call them “deuterocanonical” (second canon). The branches which don’t call them “apocrypha” (hidden things, I think). Does the Jewish tradition have any word for them at all, or does it simply ignore them?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_apocrypha

And the answer is in the wiki link above:  (Hebrew: הספרים החיצוניים, romanized: HaSefarim haChitzoniyim, lit. 'the outer books')
